# My JEE code doesn't treat the "if" bloc eventhough it's true

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of Hashmap that I'm going to use later.
What I'm doing is getting an `ArrayList<String>` called **groups** and another one called **types** , from the front.

So far I was able to get each type with its corresponding group in an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` called **typeGroup** and I'm getting this result `typegroup  : [{traitement=FC}, {traitement=FP}, {traitement=FE}, {information=ZD}, {information=ZX}, {information=ZY}, {information=ZZ}, {rapport=FP}, {rapport=FD}, {rapport=JD}, {ddm=FD}, {ddm=FT}, {ddm=JD}]` .

What I want now is to map them into an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` called **newMap** but this time each type will have its corresponding groups and I got this result `newMap    : [{information=ZD,ZX,ZY,ZZ}, {rapport=FP,FD,JD}, {ddm=FD,FT,JD}]`

My problem is it doesn't get all the objects it's supposed to give me this result `newMap    : [{traitement=FC,FP,FE}, {information=ZD,ZX,ZY,ZZ}, {rapport=FP,FD,JD}, {ddm=FD,FT,JD}]`

Here's my code :

```
HashMap<String, Integer> countmap = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> typeGroup = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> ty = new HashSet<>(types);
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(ty);

   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < types.size(); j++) {
            if (arr.get(i).equals(types.get(j))) {
                count++;}
        }
        countmap.put(arr.get(i), count);
    }

    System.out.println("arr :"+arr);
    System.out.println("countmap  : " + countmap);

    for (int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> TG = new HashMap<>();
        TG.put(types.get(i), groups.get(i));
        typeGroup.add(TG);
    }

    System.out.println("typegroup  : " + typeGroup);

    boolean test = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < typeGroup.size()- 1 ; i++) {
        String key = "";
        System.out.println((typeGroup.get(i).keySet()).equals(typeGroup.get(i + 1).keySet()));
        if ((typeGroup.get(i).keySet()).equals(typeGroup.get(i + 1).keySet())) {
            if ((newMap.contains(key))) {
                for (String str : typeGroup.get(i).keySet()) {
                    key = str;
                }
                HashMap<String, String> op = new HashMap<>();
                String val = "";
                for (int t1 = 0; t1 < countmap.get(key); t1++) {
                    if (val == "") {
                        val = typeGroup.get(i).get(key);
                    } else {
                        val = val + "," + typeGroup.get(i+t1).get(key)+"%";
                    }
                    op.put(key, val);
                }
                newMap.add(op);
                if (test == false) {
                    i++;
                }
                test = false;
                System.out.println("++++++++");
            }

        } else {
            test = true;
            for (String str : typeGroup.get(i + 1).keySet()) {
                key = str;
            }
            HashMap<String, String> op = new HashMap<>();
            String val = "";
            for (int t = 0; t < countmap.get(key); t++) {
                if (val == "") {
                    val = typeGroup.get(i + 1).get(key);
                } else {
                    val = val + "," + typeGroup.get(i + 1 + t).get(key);
                }
                op.put(key, val);
            }
            System.out.println("op :" +op);
            newMap.add(op);
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("countmap  : " + countmap);
    System.out.println("typeGroup : " + typeGroup);
    System.out.println("newMap    : " + newMap);
```

This is the whole result I'm getting

```
types     : [traitement, traitement, traitement, information, information, information, information, rapport, rapport, rapport, ddm, ddm, ddm]
groups    : [FC, FP, FE, ZD, ZX, ZY, ZZ, FP, FD, JD, FD, FT, JD]
arr :[traitement, rapport, ddm, information]
countmap  : {traitement=3, rapport=3, information=4, ddm=3}
typegroup  : [{traitement=FC}, {traitement=FP}, {traitement=FE}, {information=ZD}, {information=ZX}, {information=ZY}, {information=ZZ}, {rapport=FP}, {rapport=FD}, {rapport=JD}, {ddm=FD}, {ddm=FT}, {ddm=JD}]
true
false
op :{information=ZD,ZX,ZY,ZZ}
true
true
false
op :{rapport=FP,FD,JD}
true
false
op :{ddm=FD,FT,JD}
true
countmap  : {traitement=3, rapport=3, information=4, ddm=3}
typeGroup : [{traitement=FC}, {traitement=FP}, {traitement=FE}, {information=ZD}, {information=ZX}, {information=ZY}, {information=ZZ}, {rapport=FP}, {rapport=FD}, {rapport=JD}, {ddm=FD}, {ddm=FT}, {ddm=JD}]
newMap    : [{information=ZD,ZX,ZY,ZZ}, {rapport=FP,FD,JD}, {ddm=FD,FT,JD}]
```

Comment: The code skips the key of the very first group because of the condition ` if ((newMap.contains(key)))` - on the very first iteration the key is `""`. Please be also aware that in Java the index of first item in `List` is `0` - the `for` loop in the code starts with 1, however, that is an error.

Comment: One would get much simpler code if the model for the problem was better. A `Hashmap` is not a good structure to store two strings together. Why not make a simple class for that? And a second one for the situation with one key and several values?